# explicit statement works, but function modeled on statement returns empty list

Tags: r, function

I have an explicit statement that works just fine, but fails when I try to convert it into a function, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  I have:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
string <-c("apple", "grape", "orange", "tomato", "pear", "plum")
df <- data.frame(id, string)
```

If I say

```
list_value = paste0(df$string, sep = ";")
```

I get the following character vector returned, which is what I want:

```
list_value = "apple;""grape;""orange;""tomato;""pear;""plum;"
```

But if I try to write a function

```
concat <- function(d, n, s) {
   list_value = paste0({{d$n}}, sep = s)
   return(list_value)
 }
```

then ask for

```
test <- concat(df, string, ";")
print(test)
```

all I get is ";". Why does the explicit statement work, but the function returns an empty list? I specifically need the function, because I want to loop over it for unique values in the id column of the df.

thanks

*edited to fix misplaced ;

Comment: Yes, `paste0()` doesn't have an argument named `sep`, so that expression is the same as `paste0(df$string, ";")` which always just adds a semicolon at the end, it doesn't use it as a separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `{{d$n}}` doesn't mean anything special in R:  it's just the same as `d$n`.  Since your dataframe didn't have a column named `"n"`, it gives `NULL`, and you get the result you saw.

You've probably been confused because some `tidyverse` functions evaluate things like `{{d$n}}` in a special way.  But your function doesn't use any of the `tidyverse` non-standard evaluation, so it's just R you're working with.

To get what you want, you would have to write the function as

```
concat <- function(d, n, s) {
   list_value = paste0(d[[deparse(substitute(n))]], sep = s)
   return(list_value)
 }
```

which is pretty ugly.  I'd recommend specifying that the second argument needs to be a string, then you could write

```
concat2 <- function(d, n, s) {
   list_value = paste0(d[[n]], sep = s)
   return(list_value)
 }
```

but you would have to call it as

```
concat2(df, "string", ";")
```